# Launching Android Netflix App while entering Credentials Using Another test App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Netflix Login App in which user can enter Netflix Id And Password and then login Page redirects the user to Netflix Android App. I'm facing issue in passing the Netflix Id And Password from my App to Netflix App.Till now I'm only able to launch Netflix App from my test App. Please Help me in resolving this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@overrideMyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

Color containerColor = Colors.red;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Netflix Sign-In App'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Form(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Email',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Password',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                            ),
                            obscureText: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await LaunchApp.openApp(
                              androidPackageName: 'com.netflix.mediaclient',
                              iosUrlScheme: 'nflx://',
                              //appStoreLink:
                              //'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/   app/pulse-secure/id945832041',
                              // openStore: false
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text('SIGN-IN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )));
}
```

}

Comment: My main focus in building this app is to automate the login process, user should be able to use my app to login into other app. with a click.

Comment: `I'm facing issue in passing the Netflix Id And Password` What issue? You can edit your question and add necessary updates to it.

Comment: I  can open another App using my App(using above Code) but how can I pass the User Credentials from my App to another App.

Answer (score 0):

`external_app_launcher` doesn't have API to pass data to app instead I think you should try [firebase dynamic link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)